# Merge a task with TFS

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS source control, and I fixed bug, and when I checked in my changes, I associate the check in with the task (that represent the bug).

Now, the complicated stuff.
I want to merge the changes associated with that task, into another branch.

I couldn't find a way to do it in Visual Studio team system, or TFS source control explorer.

do you know any other tool that can be a help.

I am telling you, if I cannot do it in TFS, then TFS is lacking a core requirement, because I can do that in free other free source controls.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFS allows merge a changeset.

Answer (score 6):

You need to look up the changeset # that was associated with the bug.  Or find a 3rd party tool that wraps this functionality for you.  (would take about 10 minutes to write one if you don't care about handling all the edge cases)

The native Merge commands do not let you use bug #s as input because bugs can be associated with an arbitrary number of changesets which may not be contiguous.  My understanding is that TFS 2010 improves this in some common scenarios, but the general case is not soluble.

Comment: A bit hard to understand the way the question is phrased but I think the op just wants to merge one changset for a given workitem? At least given that the op accepted the other answer that is. Interesting idea for a feature for version next. some type of merge function off of the workitem for working with multiple changsets, cool idea.

Comment: I wrote a tool to do that once, merge all changesets associated with a workitem. Unfortunately it caused more problems than it solved. The concept is inherently flawed, in TFS at least. It inherently supports the anti-pattern of "cherry pick" merging, which is something that TFS does not support well at all.